# Creating a Crosstabulation matrix with just two variables

Tags: r, matrix

I apologise if the question is too simplistic but I am only now starting in R and Statistic-related problems.

I'm using data from the in-built `infert` dataset, and for an assignment I need to build a **crosstabulation matrix** where the columns will be the `induced` variable and the rows will be the `spontaneous` variable.

Here's an example of the matrix for anyone not familiar with `infert`:

```
> infert
    education age parity induced case spontaneous stratum pooled.stratum
1      0-5yrs  26      6       1    1           2       1              3
2      0-5yrs  42      1       1    1           0       2              1
3      0-5yrs  39      6       2    1           0       3              4
4      0-5yrs  34      4       2    1           0       4              2
5     6-11yrs  35      3       1    1           1       5             32
6     6-11yrs  36      4       2    1           1       6             36
7     6-11yrs  23      1       0    1           0       7              6
8     6-11yrs  32      2       0    1           0       8             22
9     6-11yrs  21      1       0    1           1       9              5
10    6-11yrs  28      2       0    1           0      10             19
11    6-11yrs  29      2       1    1           0      11             20
...
247   12+ yrs  29      1       0    0           1      82             43
248   12+ yrs  23      1       0    0           1      83             40
```

After that, I also need to apply a **chi-squared contigency table test** to the results to see if the two variables are linked or not.

The thing is, due to my inexperience I do not know where to begin. Google yielded no relevant results and I couldn't find any methods() or tutorials about building a crosstabulation matrix.

Hoever, a very relevant page that also contains info for a chi-squared test method I found is [this](http://www.statmethods.net/stats/frequencies.html), though it uses an outside package, `gmodels`.

Any ways to do this with in-built R functions or will I have to get `gmodels`?

Comment: @MarkHeckmann I've linked to that very same page within my question. Please read it thoroughly next time you comment.

Comment: Sorry for the irritation. Maybe I should have added: "It's all described on the page you linked.":  `attach(infert);
mytable <- table(spontaneous, induced);
chisq.test(mytable)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `table` to create the contingency table:

```
freq <- table(infert[c("induced", "spontaneous")])
#        spontaneous
# induced  0  1  2
#       0 67 47 29
#       1 45 16  7
#       2 29  8  0
```

Now, you can use `chisq.test` to test whether the two variables are independent:

```
chisq.test(freq)

#  Pearson's Chi-squared test
#
# data:  freq
# X-squared = 18.198, df = 4, p-value = 0.001129
```